# Making a textbox readonly on dropdown list selection without a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, postback, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make a textbox read only on the selection of a combo box, without the web page posting back? I am creating a sickness form, and if the user selects that a doctor has not been seen, i wish to make specific text boxes read only. The problem with the postback event is that it will not open the modal window after postback, it only opens if the button is once again clicked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use, javascript for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make textbox readonly in javascript use following code. Call this code on combox box event.

aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedIndexChanged="func()" Width="150px">
```

JS Code:

```
 function func()
    {
    var el = document.getElementById('txt');
      this.setAttribute('readonly');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to javascript (as of yesterday!) how would i find the combo box selection event within the javascript part of my aspx page?

Comment: See the post, you will find the onselectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownID" runat="server" onselectedIndexChanged="myFunction()" >
```

put the below code in aspx file inside form or content control

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        var dropDown= document.getElementById("<%=dropDownID.ClientID %>")
        var ddlSelectedValue= dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
        if(ddlSelectedValue=="desiredValue")
        {
          var textBox = document.getElementById("<%=textBoxId.ClientID %>");
          textBox.disabled=true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please show some effort to get it work.

Comment: I have put this within the form and it says that it cant find "myFunction()" when running the webpage. I am putting effort, but its hard when I have seen javascript for less than 24 hrs aha.

Comment: ok remove the onSelectedIndexChanged from aspx file and write dropDownID.Attributes.Add("onChange", "myFunction();"); in Page_load method. hope this will sort it out.